# Adding char string into sprintf

Tags: c, char, printf, pic

I'm programming a PIC for some temp sensing. The final output is sent via UART to a PC. The MSB of the temperature sensor ID is used to determine where the sensor is located.

I've just added the guilty chunk of the code I'm using (no point boring u with the rest). The issue is with the location[] char I'm using. I've tried it a few ways (*location, location[7]), but most fail to compile. The way below does compile, but nothing is displayed in the %s after "Location=". I also tried %c, but still nothing was displayed.

```
void convert_1820_send_temp(int *buff)
{
  // have removed other variables
  char location[];

  // Determine location based on sensor id
  if (dev_adr[7] == 181)
  {
    strcpy(location, "outside");
  }
  if (dev_adr[7] == 30)
  {
    strcpy(location, "ceiling");
  }
  if (dev_adr[7] == 46)
  {
    strcpy(location, "under  ");
  }
  if (dev_adr[7] == 18)
  {
    strcpy(location, "inside ");
  }
  else
  {
    strcpy(location, "unknown");
  }
  sprintf(s,
      "Temp=%c%d.%d degrees C, sensor=\"%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\",Location=%s\r\n",
      negSign, tempWhole, decimal, dev_adr[7], dev_adr[6], dev_adr[5],
      dev_adr[4], dev_adr[3], dev_adr[2], dev_adr[1], dev_adr[0]), location;

  USARTWriteString(s);
}
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Don't use strcpy, assign to pointer location directly. Using a switch case would make code more readable. Do you inted to keep last location outside sprintf?

Comment: Thanks alk, forgot about the string length + 1 rule :)

Comment: @alk `char location[];` is a constraint violation. It's not the same as `char *location;` .

Comment: @MattMcNabb: You are correct, gcc as an extension defines a it to be `location [0]`.. Cleaning up the temp brain laps ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you are trying to put data into an array for which no space has been allocated.

Instead, use the following. (I also refactored the `if` statements into a `switch`). The location is a pointer that is made to point to the string you want. This is safer and more efficient than copying characters with `strcpy`.

```
char const *location;

switch (dev_addr[7]) {
case 181:
    location = "outside";
   break;
case 30:
    location = "ceiling";
   break;
default:
    location = "unknown";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I gave it a try as I also like the switch. When I compile the code and get the following error (x4), which relates to the location = "xxxxxxx";:-  temp_uart_16f877_ROM_read_working.c:397: warning: (359) illegal conversion between pointer types
pointer to const unsigned char -> pointer to unsigned char

Comment: Saying that it does still compile, will test it out. Tried it, still nothing displayed in the %s.

Comment: OK but use `char const *location;`.

Comment: @Markus if line 397 is `location = "xxxxxxxx";` then the compiler message is somewhat bogus, since these are `char` and not `unsigned char` (even if plain char is unsigned , it still should not say that); and also this conversion is not illegal. Are you sure you are using a C compiler?

Comment: I'm using MPLAB X and the MICROCHIP XC8 compiler, so it's definitely c.

Comment: is using %s correct or should I be using %c to add the value in the sprintf?

Answer (score 3):

You need to move `,location` inside the parentheses.

Comment: Darn typo's... that certainly wouldn't help :), thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you had should not compile... try this:

```
void convert_1820_send_temp(int *buff)
{
    // have removed other variables
    char location[8]; // Minimum of 8 for 7 char strings below
    char s[512];

    // Determine location based on sensor id
    switch( dev_adr[7] ) {
    case 181:
        strcpy(location, "outside");
        break;
    case 30:
        strcpy(location, "ceiling");
        break;
    case 46:
        strcpy(location, "under  ");
        break
    case 18:
        strcpy(location, "inside ");
        break;
    default:
        strcpy(location, "unknown");
        break;
    }
    sprintf(s, "Temp=%c%d.%d degrees C, sensor=\"%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d,Location=\"%s\"\r\n",
        negSign, tempWhole, decimal, dev_adr[7], dev_adr[6], dev_adr[5],
        dev_adr[4], dev_adr[3], dev_adr[2], dev_adr[1], dev_adr[0], location );

    USARTWriteString(s);   
}
```

Comment: Sorry I do have the char s[64], just left that out as part of the cull. Will try the rest as I was still not getting any value appearing

Comment: Awesome, all sorted, thanks to all, a combination of my badly placed parentheses and incorrectly defined char were the cause. Thanks again.